# CSS check username

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to make like in this example below.
[image]

My problem is to put the message: **"Sorry, such user already exists! Please try another username."** before PERSONAL INFORMATION...

My check works in my form.

```
if($username_check->rowCount() == 0){

        } else {
            $errors['username_error'] = "Sorry, such user already exists! Please try another username. ";
            $username = "";
        }
    }
```

How to put the error message in top in "PERSONAL INFORMATION..." in CSS ? I don't to put a  on the PHP ? I don't think.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="contenair_reg">
            <span class="regtxtcolor"><i class="far fa-address-card"> Personal Information:</i></span>
                <div class='reg_content_container'>
                <p>Please use English letters and numbers in all field for registration before creating an account.</p>
                </div>
```

Do you have an idea ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="contenair_reg">

    <?
      if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0) {
          echo "<ul class=\"errors\">";
          foreach ($errors as $type=>$message) {
              echo "<li>$message</li>";
          }
          echo "</ul>";
      }
     ?>

        <span class="regtxtcolor"><i class="far fa-address-card"> Personal Information:</i></span>
            <div class='reg_content_container'>
            <p>Please use English letters and numbers in all field for registration before creating an account.</p>
            </div>
```

Your PHP code creates an array of errors if there are any errors. This code loops over that array and outputs each error message as a bullet point. You may need to format it with CSS to make it red etc.

Comment: thank for your help... I have 2 errors messages, the first "Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\wamp64\www\superbtc\inscription.php on line 9" and the second " Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\superbtc\inscription.php on line 9"

Comment: I added a check to kill that error to the code above

Comment: @ user1491032: ohhhh thank youuuuu a lot it workssssss !! :-) I am happy ^^ thank you very much.